# Use existing columns as index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

How can I tell `pandas` to index an existing data frame by two or more columns already in the data frame?

```
In [14]: df
OUt [14]:

  date         group    colour    count
0 2014-10-08   1        yellow    3
1 2014-10-08   2        yellow    6
3 2014-10-08   3        yellow    3
4 2014-10-08   1        blue      1
5 2014-10-08   2        blue      2
```

On this example I would like to index df by `date`, `group` and `colour`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = df.set_index(['date', 'group', 'colour'])
```

yields

```
                         count
date       group colour       
2014-10-08 1     yellow      3
           2     yellow      6
           3     yellow      3
           1     blue        1
           2     blue        2
```

Ref: [DataFrame.set_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)